# Does mathematical modeling assist in learning how to derive equations?

Tags: functional-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am hoping someone can provide a starting point to the question: **Would mathematical modeling be a good place to start learning how to derive equations and functions from a set of data?**

For example, how does one come up with a function to show supply and demand in economics, or a mathematical model related to fluid dynamics in physics? I am trying to learn mathematics intuitively. I have taken both differential and integral calculus, but I do not feel I learned how to properly derive equations. I need to improve my mathematical reasoning. I am hoping that learning the basics of mathematical modeling will help as I can practice finding equations without having them given to me.  If I have to go back to basic word problems, so be it.

Comment: "Mathematical modelling" is a very vague term, but it *is* about deriving equations to help understand things. I don't know how this question can be answered, can you be more specific?